# Windows Server not receiving traffic from Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, server, window

I have a Windows Server 2019 that is trying to reach out to a Ubuntu VM (on a completely different network, different cloud provider etc.)

I can ping the Ubuntu VM from the windows server
I can see the traffic is being allowed in the logs.
I can see the ack in the Wireshark packet captures.

I tried disabling the Windows Firewall and I am still not getting a response from the Ubuntu machine.

The error I get on the windows machine is "the connection party did not respond after a period of time "

This Windows Server 2019 is a fresh install. Is there anything that is disabled by default that could cause this issue?